# how to create an ubuntu environment when using Docker on MAC computer with django

Tags: python, reactjs, python-3.x, django, docker

I am super new to Docker and i am trying to grasp a concept.

Goal: I am trying to create this tech stack

```
create a Ubuntu OS
install python
install django/DRF
install postgresql
install reactJS
```

So far I have only been able to install python, django...

## Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /code

COPY requirements.txt /code

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /django-docker/
```

## Docker compose

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

My question is mainly on how do I install or add **Ubuntu** on the tech stack mentioned above or is it really necessary to have Ubuntu if i intend to deploy my tech stack to AWS in the future so other developers can work on the same project quickly when they setup their machines?

Comment: You can install all of those technologies directly on your Mac, and the underlying environment is close enough to Linux that you'll probably be 95% successful in running your code unmodified.  Those are also extremely routine, so as long as you make sure to list your requirements out in your `Pipfile`/`package.json` other developers will not have trouble reproducing the setup.  I wouldn't unnecessarily drag Docker into it.

Comment: The point of docker is to be independent of os's, so with the current setup, a dev can easily run and deploy a django app, if they needed something extra, say install nginx, they can do so with the RUN command e.g `RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y nginx`, hope it helps.

Comment: @PeterNdungu thanks this is the explanation i was trying to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see your Dockerfile, you have specified base image as **python:3.7**.

If you visit the dockerfile of the base image python:3.7 [here](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/8167dd2574bb503a131d262c0c5721c6ba02c928/3.7/buster/Dockerfile), you can see that basically you are installing a debian os and then python.To be more clear,If the image name is python:3.7, you get a docker image of debain with python 3.7 installed.

Now if you want to install ubuntu, you can set the base image as ubuntu:[tag] and then install each dependencies (python 3.7 , django,postgresql,reactsjs).

You can view [this](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/base-image-python-docker-images/) article which will help you to decide base docker image for your use case.

Comment: thank you thats exactly what i was looking for in terms of answer to understand

Comment: @cu__007 Also , If you are using docker, you need not worry about the OS they install in their environment. Only requirement is to have docker runtime in their system.

Comment: yes someone above in the comments also mentioned the same and now i understand the concept. thank you so much!